# GitHub Tag action does not add tag

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to add tags to all commits that pass checks. I started with a template that includes the tests.

[image]

Everything runs as expected, however, when I check the tags, it does not show any were added.

[image]

Here is my full `build.yml`:

```yaml
# Automatically build the project and run any configured tests for every push
# and submitted pull request. This can help catch issues that only occur on
# certain platforms or Java versions, and provides a first line of defence
# against bad commits.

name: build
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: ['*']
  push:
    branches: ['master']

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        # Use these Java versions
        java: [
          1.8,  # Minimum supported by Minecraft
          11,   # Current Java LTS
          15    # Latest version
        ]
        # and run on both Linux and Windows
        os: [ubuntu-20.04, windows-latest]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: bump version and push tag
        id: tag_version
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && runner.os == 'Linux' && matrix.java == '11' }}
        uses: mathieudutour/github-tag-action@v5.1
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          create_annotated_tag: true
      - name: validate gradle wrapper
        uses: gradle/wrapper-validation-action@v1
      - name: setup jdk ${{ matrix.java }}
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: ${{ matrix.java }}
      - name: make gradle wrapper executable
        if: ${{ runner.os != 'Windows' }}
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - name: build
        run: ./gradlew build
      - name: capture build artifacts
        if: ${{ runner.os == 'Linux' && matrix.java == '11' }} # Only upload artifacts built from LTS java on one OS
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Artifacts
          path: build/libs/
```

And here are my actions run: https://github.com/cloewen8/Corntopia/actions

I have been working on getting this working for the past hour. I tried moving the "bump version and push tag" task from the end to right after checkout, adding and removing the id, changing were `github_token` is defined, making the tag annotated, tried the previous release of the task, using the tag in a release (said new_tag was not defined), even following the example provided for the task exactly.

Am I doing anything wrong? Anything else I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is the issue with action itself. Because it doesn't create a tag properly.

I got it (almost) working with this

```yaml
- name: Bump version and push tag
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && runner.os == 'Linux' && matrix.java == '11' }}
        uses: anothrNick/github-tag-action@1.26.0
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          WITH_V: true
```

```
Is master a match for main
pre_release = true
From https://github.com/kmadof/github-actions-manual
 * [new branch]      kmadof-patch-1 -> origin/kmadof-patch-1
 * [new branch]      test           -> origin/test
 * [new tag]         v1.4           -> v1.4
 * [new tag]         v1.5           -> v1.5
 * [new tag]         v1.6           -> v1.6
 * [new tag]         v1.7           -> v1.7
 * [new tag]         v1.8           -> v1.8
 * [new tag]         v1.9           -> v1.9
 * [new tag]         v1.91          -> v1.91
 * [new tag]         v1.92          -> v1.92
 * [new tag]         v1.93          -> v1.93
 * [new tag]         v1.94          -> v1.94
fatal: ambiguous argument '0.0.0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
[main] Modified SO workflow [skip ci]
minor
v0.1.0-3ef4b69
This branch is not a release branch. Skipping the tag creation.
```

But this is rather to a mess which I have in this repo :)

To sum up, please try with `anothrNick/github-tag-action@1.26.0` and report an issue for `mathieudutour/github-tag-action@v5.1`